# i need other solutions with Yii Multilanguage via GET to optimize SEO

Tags: php, yii, internationalization

I have a problem, I'm using a method translations of yii 1 in my multilingual website and is as follows. sorry if I did not explain well but am new yii.

I think the class that is responsible for building the url depending on the selected language in the components folder spreading CUrlManager

```
/ **
* We extend the class urlManager
* /
MyCUrlManager class extends CUrlManager
{
    public function createUrl ($ route, $ params = array (), $ ampersand = '&')
    {
        if (! isset ($ params ['language']))
        $ Params ['language'] = Yii :: app () -> language;
        return parent :: createUrl ($ route, $ params, $ ampersand);
    }
}
```

then the config / main I do the following

```
'UrlManager' => array (
...
'Class' => 'application.components.MyCUrlManager'
...
)
```

establish languages ​​in the array configuration,

```
'SourceLanguage' => 'is',
'Language' => 'is',
```

In Controller I do the following:

```
/ **
* Builder main controller
*param [String] $ id id driver father
*param [String] $ module referers
* /
public function __construct ($ id, $ module = null) {
parent :: __ construct ($ id, $ module);
Yii :: app () -> language = (isset ($ _ GET ['language'])) $ _ GET ['language']: Yii :: app () -> language;
}
 
/ **
* Method to create the url of the selected language
*param String $ lang [description]
*return [Type] [description]
* /
public function createMultilanguageReturnUrl ($ lang = 'en') {
$ Arr = array ('language' => $ lang);
 
if (count ($ _ GET)> 0) {
$ Arr = $ _GET;
$ Arr ['language'] = $ lang;
}
 
return $ this-> createUrl ('', $ arr);
}
```

and finally indicated the language on a link

```
$ this-> createMultilanguageReturnUrl ('en')
```

make a menu and submenu with CMenu and finally I quedaria something like this in the url

```
/mysite/home/index?Language=es
```

link what I did: http://daniarlandis.es/2014/02/19/yii-multilenguaje-mediante-get-para-optimizar-seo/

the problem is that I produce many errors in the redirection of view, also when I open a link in a new tab is placed back on the default language EN, then I wonder know:

I wonder if it is possible to implement this method but with a session variable? And if it could be implemented together with a datalist?

I used the same solutions presented here, this has been what has worked best for me but not as optimal

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: T o  m a n y  s p a c e s. Don't use them before a variable and almost anywhere. Or is that a copy/pase error?

Answer (score 0):

You can create you `UrlManager` like [TsUrlManager](https://github.com/TaronSaribekyan/TsTranslation/blob/master/components/TsUrlManager.php). You can change param name from `_lang` to `language` (as in your code)